Changing PDF's version using Python
I'm trying to change a PDF's version to 1.4. I used PyPDF2 BUT It can only produce version 1.3 !
from PyPDF2 import PdfMerger

fileIn = pdf_document
fileOut = 'test.pdf'
metadata = {u'/Version': 'PDF-1.4'}

merger = PdfMerger()
with open(fileIn, 'rb') as fh_in:
    merger.append(fh_in)
    merger.add_metadata(metadata)

with open(fileOut, 'wb') as fh_out:
    merger.write(fh_out) 

Is there any other method to change the Version to 1.4?
Thanks!

because as a requirement in a project the pdf needs to have version that is between 1.4 and 1.7 (ideally 1.4). yet I can only change it to 1.3 using PyPDF2 :/

qpdf --min-version=1.4 in.pdf out.pdf

More info on qpdf here. The --min-version switch upgrades in.pdf to 1.4 if it's version is less than that, or keeps the version otherwise.

Your question was asked before
How can I set the PDF version with PyPDF2?
The basic answer was PyPDF2 could only produce %PDF-1.3 since it could not edit %PDF-1.4 objects.
You could consider the answers there.
So easily edit the Pypdf2 writer by change 3 to 4 in approx line 140 of _writer.py
class PdfWriter:
    """
    This class supports writing PDF files out, given pages produced by another
    class (typically :class:`PdfReader<PyPDF2.PdfReader>`).
    """

    def __init__(self, fileobj: StrByteType = "") -> None:
        self._header = b"%PDF-1.3"

The alternative is using any binary editor such as Python simply replace the 3 with 4 in the first line of the PDF before or after save.
See current status in replacement PyPDF docs.
pypdf2 https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/user/pdf-version-support.html#pdf-feature-support-by-pypdf2
https://github.com/py-pdf/pypdf/blob/c091cd37f9702bddfbb98fae0ae811abc3efec3c/docs/user/pdf-version-support.md
